# Use Action Filter to limited on the number of access to action for each user

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Assume we have an action and we want limited on the number of access in period of times for each user, for example user 'A' can't access more than 10 times in 5mins to the sample action, and I am interesting in implement it by Action filter does any one know about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a custom authorize filter that will store the number of calls of a given action per user in the cache. By configuring a cache expiration policy, the value will be automatically evicted after the period expires.

```
public class AuthorizeWithThrottleAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private class Attempts
    {
        public int NumberOfAccess { get; set; }
    }

    public int Seconds { get; private set; }
    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public AuthorizeWithThrottleAttribute(int seconds, int count)
    {
        Seconds = seconds;
        Count = count;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var rd = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
        var action = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
        var controller = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
        // Remark: if you are using areas maybe you could also want
        // to constrain the key per area

        var key = string.Format("throttle-{0}-{1}-{2}", httpContext.User.Identity.Name, controller, action);
        var policy = new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(Seconds),
        };

        // Here we are using the new caching API introduced in .NET 4.0:
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx
        // If you are using an older version of the framework you could use
        // the legacy HttpContext.Cache instead which offers the same expiration
        // policy features as the new
        var attempts = MemoryCache.Default.Get(key) as Attempts;
        if (attempts == null)
        {
            attempts = new Attempts();
            MemoryCache.Default.Set(key, attempts, policy);
        }

        if (attempts.NumberOfAccess < Count)
        {
            attempts.NumberOfAccess++;
            return true;
        }
        httpContext.Items["throttled"] = true;
        return false;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var throttled = filterContext.HttpContext.Items["throttled"];
        if (throttled != null && (bool)throttled)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict;
            filterContext.Result = new ContentResult
            {
                Content = string.Format("You may only call this action {0} times every {1} seconds", Count, Seconds),
                ContentType = "text/plain"
            };
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

And then decorate:

```
[AuthorizeWithThrottle(10, 5)]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Thank you Darin, there is just a question: how can implement this code to show error message like validation attributes inside the view? I mean the user can see the view, but can't access to the control? is there any way?

Comment: @dotNetist, instead of using an authorization filter as in my example you could write a custom validation attribute that you could apply to your view model.

Answer (score 0):

you could put the "Count" into a shared place, such as a Session.

Do this in `OnActionExecuting`, and considering concurrent issues, you'll need to lock the session before you bump the access count, and release it ASAP.

if User 'A' meets access limit, then you could do a redirect by setting

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("route name", "route parameters")
```

Comment: Not a good Idea. session is per browser. the user can open a new browser and get new session with count == 0!

Comment: a new browser is a new "user". does it make sense limiting the real user accessing from a different browser/computer?

Answer (score 0):

I did something recently which throttles the number of times a user can access a url in a given time scale, i went down the approach of sticking the item into the httpcontext cache with an expiration.

You can see my blog post on it at http://www.jambr.co.uk/Article/action-filter-request-throttle

It isn't exactly what you need but can be easily modified, instead of storing an empty object in the cache, you could store your count, and then you could also store it with a sliding expiration rather than a fixed one?  Any questions just ask.